# How to make variable visible to JavaExec task in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How can I make compilerConstants visible to compile task in the example below? It works fine with foo task.

Or maybe someone can suggest a better way of doing this? Basically I need to be able to set up desktop or mobile compilation and it differs only by those parameters.

EDIT: This is a really simplified example of my situation. My actual compile task has 20+ lines of stuff and only compilerConstants is the one variable between 3 different setups.

```
String AIR_HOME = System.getenv('FLEX_HOME')
def compilerConstants = []

task setupDesktop << {
    compilerConstants.push('-define=BUILD::desktop,true')
}

task setupMobile << {
    compilerConstants.push('-define=BUILD::desktop,false')
}

task compile (type: JavaExec) {
    main = "com.adobe.flash.compiler.clients.MXMLC"
    classpath = files("${AIR_HOME}/lib/compiler.jar")

    def argsList = []

    // compiler constants
    argsList = (argsList << compilerConstants).flatten()
    println 'compile args: ' + argsList

    args = argsList
}

task foo << {
    def argsList = []
    argsList = (argsList << compilerConstants).flatten()
    println 'foo args: ' + argsList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `compilerConstants` is an act of configuration, and therefore shouldn't be done by a task. The solution is to declare two `JavaExec` tasks, "compileDesktop" and "compileMobile". Commonalities can be factored out, but it may not be worth it in this case.

Comment: This case was just a simplified example and I hoped people would realize it. In my real case, there's 20+ lines of identical stuff going in each 3 compile task and that's why I would like to find out a way how to introduce just those compilerConstants to each of them.

Comment: There is no way for people to realize this unless you mention it in the question. Commonalities can be configured once and for all with a statement such as `tasks.withType(JavaExec) { ... }`.